# How to pass method as parameter in Go?

Tags: go, struct, parameter-passing

i just want to pass some methods that they belongs to 'any' struct to their receiver method.

These are prototype methods.

```golang
func (r *Rules) Checker(fn ...func()) {}
func (r *Rules) CheckEmpty() {}
func (r *Rules) CheckMax()  {}
```

and what i want is here:

```golang
v.Rule.Checker(
    v.Rule.CheckEmpty(),
    v.Rule.CheckMax(),
)
```

But i think function types are not equal and the program giving me error 'type void type as type func()'.
Is there a way to call these methods as i wanted to ?

Comment: `type void type as type func()` is not an error in Go. Can you post the actual error you receive? Looks like what you probably want here is `v.Rule.Checker(v.Rule.CheckEmpty, v.Rule.CheckMax)` - passing the functions rather than calling them and passing their return values (which they do not have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass the function itself to `Checker`, and not the result of the function call. To do that, drop the `()` after the function name so the function is not being called:

```
v.Rule.Checker(
    v.Rule.CheckEmpty,
    v.Rule.CheckMax,
)
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand it properly now.